# Option for dynamic prototypes not appearing in the attributes inspector

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView that I just added to my project and the option is not appearing for me to choose the content (dynamic prototypes or static cells).  I have used UITableViews in other iOS projects, but for some reason it's not appearing this time.  I'm using XCode 4.4.1.

Here is the a screenshot of the way it looks in another project:

[image: A working example from another project]

Here is the screenshot of in the project I'm working in now where it's not appearing:

[image: Screenshot that is missing properties]

Does anyone know what I am missing? I can't figure out what I have done differently.

Comment: It seems like they have merged Content dynamic with Style, Does your old project has "Custom" option in style?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those options only appear for TableViews in storyboards. For some reason, you can't edit those properties on a UITableView in a nib file.